# What is this matrix called?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite graph where $V$ has $n$ elements so that $V=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$.

Now, define $a_{ij}$ to be 1 if $(v_i,v_j)\in E$ and 0 otherwise. What is this $n\times n$ matrix $(a_{ij})$ called? In some texts, it is defined as an "incidence matrix", but the definition of incidence matrix in wikipedia is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).